# How would to Verify two strings same length and have one value per character no duplicates Java

Tags: java, string, match

How to verify that two string match each other with characters. One character matches one character no duplicates.

```
"ABC" --> "DEF" True
"BIKE" --> "FGEH" True
"Alex"--> "BoB" --> False duplicate characters B and different size length.
"Mom"---> "DaD" --> False duplicate letters D.

static void match(String str1, String str2){
    char[] inp1 = str1.toCharArray();
      char[] inp2 = str2.toCharArray();
      for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < str2.length(); j++) {
        if (inp1[i] == inp[j]) {
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Too broad. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm lost when I try to compare them. How do you compare for duplicate letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot the logic is there the fine tuning is all you

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(" Result:"+sillyStringCompare("ABC", "DEF"));
    System.out.println(" Result:"+sillyStringCompare("BIKE", "FGEH"));
    System.out.println(" Result:"+sillyStringCompare("Alex", "BoB"));
    System.out.println(" Result:"+sillyStringCompare("Mom", "DaD"));
}

private static boolean sillyStringCompare(String stringOne, String stringTwo){
    System.out.print('"'+stringOne+'"'+" ---> "+'"'+stringTwo+'"');
    if(stringOne.length()!=stringTwo.length())
        return false;

    if(duplicateLetterInString(stringOne, 0))
        return false;

    if(duplicateLetterInString(stringTwo, 0))
        return false;

    return true;
}

private static boolean duplicateLetterInString(String string, int index) {
    char compareChar = string.charAt(index);

    char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        if (charArray[i] == compareChar && i != index)
            return true;
    }

    return string.length() > index + 1 && duplicateLetterInString(string, ++index);
}
```

The output:

```
"ABC" ---> "DEF" Result:true
"BIKE" ---> "FGEH" Result:true
"Alex" ---> "BoB" Result:false
"Mom" ---> "DaD" Result:false
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! What does  if(letterInString(stringOne, 0)) means especially 0.

Comment: I refactored it checks for a duplicate letter in the string

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Map to map letters in string 1 to string 2:

```
static boolean match(String str1, String str2){
    // First check len
    if (str1.length() != str2.length()) return false;

    // Create the map
    Map<Character, Character> letterMap = new HashMap<Character, Character>();

    // Compare
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
        char c1 = str1.charAt(i);
        char c2 = str2.charAt(i);
        // New letter in string 1?
        if (!letterMap.containsKey(c1)) {
            // Make sure the letter c2 is not already mapped to something else
            if (letterMap.containsValue(c2)) return false;
            // Add to map
            letterMap.put(c1, c2);
        }
        // Already in map? (Not a new letter in str1)
        else {
            // Make sure it's the correct c2
            if (letterMap.get(c1) != c2) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What does quotation ! mark mean where you wrote !letterMap?

Comment: @vladbelo That's a logical "not". Meaning "if not letterMap contains c1...." or "if letterMap does not contain c1...."

Comment: If I delete ! explanation mark  ((!letterMap.contaninsKey) it gives me an error thread meain java.lang NullPointException

Comment: @vladbelo If you remove the `!` you are inverting the logic. So when `c1` is not in `letterMap` (the `else` is entered and) it calls `letterMap.get(c1)` which throws NPE because `c1` is not in the map yet.